# How to center the zero to one space in UV View?

Tags: uv

No matter the amount of zoom, UV 0-1 space is not visible even when numpad "." is used on a selected object. (frame selected)
How to force blender to center the zero to one space in UV View to where a somewhat human can see it?
[image]

Comment: It doesn't look as if any UVs are selected in the _UV Editor_. If nothing is selected, numpad "." will not center / zoom in on anything. Just press A to select all and try again.

Comment: ...or press the Home button as @Crantisz has answered, of course ;) But if your UVs are somewhere way off the center they won't come into view this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>Home</kbd> button. It will reset the view.

Comment: What is the difference between "Home" and numpad "." to focus on an item?

Comment: Numpad "." focuses on the selected item. If nothing is selected (like in your case), it doesn't work.

Comment: @CountQuadula The difference is, "Home" doesn't focus on an item at all, it only centers the viewport, no matter where or if an item is selected.